# Understanding それをごまかす方法として

Tags: meaning, parsing

From Naruto ch. 587

[image]

In this panel, Itachi is shown explaining how he is similar to Kabuto.

There is one part I am not sure about,

> それをごまかす方法として...

I am not sure what それ is referring to. Maybe one's failures (己の失敗)? Also, how to parse?「(それ)を(ごまかす方法)として」or「(それをごまかす方法)として」?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

それ is the object of ごまかす. The basic meaning of ごまかす is described here: [Meaning of ごまかす](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94402/5010)

I think this それ refers to the 嘘 or the truth behind that 嘘; whichever makes sense. Either way, this それを誤魔化す refers to the efforts to move away from the truth and assume the lie is the truth (i.e., he is omnipotent). The sentence is saying he was able to continue to believe he was almighty by looking down on the ability of others.